# google earth engine: ee.List() output as an integer?

Tags: google-earth-engine

may I not JSON.stringify() the output of ee.List()  ?

```
var dates = ee.List(imageCollection.get('date_range'));
print('type: ', typeof(dates));
print('JSON.stringify: ', JSON.stringify(dates));

print('Date zero: ', dates.get(0));
print('type: ', typeof(dates.get(0)))
print('JSON.stringify: ', JSON.stringify(dates.get(0)))
```

and the console says:

```
type: 
object
JSON.stringify: 
{} 

Date zero: 
1365638400000
type: 
object
JSON.stringify: 
{}
```

my end-game is to interpret dates.get(0) as an integer....

Comment: this is a duplicate of the well answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948008/convert-what-looks-like-a-number-but-isnt-to-an-integer-google-earth-engine?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are server objects.  You have to request their value (with the synchronous `getInfo()` or the asynchronous `evaluate()`) to mix and match with a client-side function like `JSON.stringify()`:

```
var dates = ee.List(imageCollection.get('date_range'));
print('type: ', typeof(dates));
print('JSON.stringify: ', JSON.stringify(dates.getInfo()));

print('Date zero: ', dates.get(0));
print('type: ', typeof(dates.get(0)))
print('JSON.stringify: ', JSON.stringify(dates.get(0).getInfo()))
```

Note that there's no need to stringify anything at this point.  i.e. `dates.get(0).getInfo()` is a `Number`:

```
print('A number: ', Number(dates.get(0).getInfo()))
```